# Static Content 404 with Magento 2 and Nginx

Tags: magento2, nginx, static-content, docker, magento2.3

**Preface:** I have read through as many posts as I can find about this issue, but I have tried all solutions suggested already.

**The Issue**
Using a quick docker setup to get a local instance of Magento 2 up for contributing development. I used this [dockerize](https://github.com/arvatoSCM/dockerize-magento2) module for convenience. I have the site up and running, but all static content is throwing 404. The homepage pulls up, and all content including the media are loaded. But none of the static content (js/css) are resolving.

**Environment Details**

- Currently on the 2.3-develop branch of the core Magento 2 repo.
- My host machine is Ubuntu 18.04
- As mentioned, I'm using [arvatorSCM/dockerize](https://github.com/arvatoSCM/dockerize-magento2) which includes:

  - Nginx
  - Redis
  - MySQL
  - I have replaced the `php` image with a local build of the same thing except using PHP 7.1

**Already tried**

- I am using the nginx.conf.sample file that comes with Magento.
- I have tried *both* `developer` mode without deploying static content and `production` mode with `setup:static-content:deploy`. Both of these result in 404's on all `pub/static...` URLs.
- I have tried disabling static content signing as well. No change in results.
- Yes I have flush, cleared, and disabled all of the caches with every test as well as emptying directories such as generated, pub/static, var/cache, var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed.

I did some debugging in the Nginx config file by adding cookies in each of the location blocks. The strange thing is the `/static/` block never seems to be executed. The cookie being added in the first line of this block never gets added to any static content responses. I also tried throwing some debugging into `pub/static.php` and it doesn't appear to ever be executed.

I understand this has to be an environmental config issue, but I am out of ideas on what to try. I have completely wiped my setup and started over multiple times, but my result is always the same.

Below are some screenshots from my testing. What's interesting is all CSS requests show as (canceled) status, but all JS show as 404. 
[image: Console errors]
[image: CSS Request]
[image: JS Request]

To clarify, my official question here is for any recommendations of what might cause the static content to 404, and if anyone has any ideas to try to resolve the issue that I haven't already tried. Thank you for your time and any assistance.

**UPDATE**

My Nginx config file, which is taken directly from the linked docker setup, but I stripped out all Magento stuff and instead included the sample file.

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
   server   php:9000;
}

server {
    listen                      80 default_server;
    listen                      443 default_server ssl;

    server_name                 magento2.docker;

    ssl_certificate             /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;

    client_max_body_size        10M;

    set                         $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;
    set                         $MAGE_MODE developer;

    include /var/www/html/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file for reference is the same as this - https://github.com/arvatoSCM/dockerize-magento2/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml

And my nginx.conf.sample file hasn't been modified from the repo - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/nginx.conf.sample

**UPDATE 2**

After some more testing I found that if I manually do the rewrite from `/pub/static/` to `/static.php?resource=$1` it results in a successful call. 
For example, if I try to go to *magento2.docker/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css* I get a 404. But if I to go *magento2.docker/static.php?resource=frontend%2FMagento%2Fluma%2Fen_US%2Fcss%2Fstyles-m.css* I get the CSS file successfully. This means the `/static/` location in the Nginx config file isn't getting properly triggered I think. I just can't figure out why.

**UPDATE 3**

I was able to get the assets to load by moving the `location /static/` blocks in `nginx.conf.sample` to be inside the `location /pub/` block as follows. This is just a temporary fix though, because it means the `alias` in pub isn't working properly I think. Anyone have suggestions on why that might be the case?

```
location /pub/ {
    add_header Set-Cookie nginxlocation="pub";
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

    # Moved from /static/
    location ~ ^/pub/static/version {
        rewrite ^/pub/static/(version[^/]+/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }
    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|json)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/pub/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/pub/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/pub/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}
```

Comment: please add your nginx sites-enable file

Comment: @AsharRiaz Updated with nginx config.

Comment: @rain2o any fix for this, having same problem in a new install of magento 2.3 on nginx

Comment: @LiamMitchell unfortunately I haven't found a solution. I used that temporary fix I posted in Update 3 for the setup at the time and I haven't been back to it in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the above (moving the /static block inside the /pub block) but it didn't work for me. In the end, what did the trick was then adding in a new block for /static as follows :

```
location /static/ {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
         rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
}
```

Note that is subtly different to the similar rewrite at the end of your code in Update 3.

Comment: Can I ask if you left the original static section as it was or replaced it with this?

Comment: I replaced it with this.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Cant believe that an out of the box install still has such a simple flaw!

Answer (score 0):

In your nginx.conf.sample file change from $MAGE_ROOT/pub to $MAGE_ROOT .
I hope it will fix your issue.

Comment: Magento 2 runs its docroot from the pub directory, so this won't work. The nginx.conf.sample file is how Magento recommends to run your Nginx setup. If I have to modify that file it means I have an issue in my environment setup. 
Either way I tried it just for a sanity check and it did not fix my issue.